# MSAccess Join SQL query - Join expression not supported

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Joining two tables together within vb.net but getting the following error:

*"Join expression not supported"*

```
SELECT * FROM (General_Counters_Table AS a INNER JOIN Timers_Table AS b ON b.ulProductionTime = a.Product_ID) INNER JOIN Timers_Table AS b ON b.ulSetupTime = a.Product_ID
```

Product_ID exists in both General_Counters_Table and Timers_Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser got confused when you join for a second time the *Timers_Table* because you use the same alias already used for the first join.

However it seems that you just want to produce a result with all fields from the A table and some fields from the B table. If this is the case you need 
to join the two tables with the common field (*Product_ID*) and add, to the SELECT statement, the fields required from the A and B table

```
 SELECT a.*, b.ulProductionTime, b.ulSetupTime, ....... 
 FROM General_Counters_Table AS a 
      INNER JOIN Timers_Table AS b ON b.Product_ID = a.Product_ID
```

Comment: In the Timers_Table - the ulProductionTime and ulSetupTime are on the same row as the matching Timers_Table Product_ID, i just want to join the two columns onto the General_Counters_Table that has the same Product_ID - too be fair there are about 10 columns i want to join to the end, is there a correct way of doing it?

Comment: If I understand well your comment then you join just one time and add the required fields to the SELECT statement